# Laravel Blade imprime html

Tags: laravel, utf-8, laravel-blade

Por Algum motivo quando uso {{ }} para interpolar, o Blade não interpreta os acentos e imprimi na tela o código html, ao invés de interpretar o código
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já quando utilizo {!! !!}, ele imprime correto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem todo o código esta sendo usado {{ }}, que é o mais recomendado pela [documentação do laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data), Em algum momento mexi em algo que não deveria e começou a dar esse erro, como posso voltar como estava antes.

Comment: No topo do layout tem `<meta charset="utf-8">` ?

Comment: Sim, <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: Recomendado quando o usuário está usando seu site, tipo telas que mostram algum resultado no seu site, então, depende da onde vem o dado para usar `{{}}` ou `{!! !!}`... ou seja, não é que seja melhor, é em que ocasião isso é melhor.